# Passing string through stat() function

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>       // For printf()
#include <sys/stat.h>   // For struct stat and stat()

struct stat stResult;

if(stat("Filename.txt", &stResult) == 0)
{
      // We have File Attributes
      // stResult.st_size is the size in bytes (I believe)
      // It also contains some other information you can lookup if you feel like it
printf("Filesize: %i", stResult.st_size);
}
else
{
      // We couldn't open the file
printf("Couldn't get file attributes...");
}
```

Now. How can I pass my own string through stat()? Like this

```
string myStr = "MyFile.txt";
stat(myStr, &stResult)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are talking about a C++ std::string, you might want to use

```
string myStr = "MyFile.txt";
stat(myStr.c_str(), &stResult)
```

so use the c_str() member-function of your string object in order to get a C string representation.

Answer (score 4):

Use the c_str() member function.

```
myStr.c_str()
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/